# Vite deploy on Azure Devops

Tags: azure, vue.js, vite

We are trying to deploy our new Vite +Vue3 app to the server, but our yaml file is out of date, it has a "--dest" option from our former Vue 2 CLI deployment..

Anyone know how to set the destination of the build in a yaml script for Azure Devops?

I am having an issue with azure devops deployment... my old script was:

current yaml step:

VUE_APP_BUILD_FILE=${{ parameters.file }} npm run build -- --dest ${{ parameters.file }}

The error is:

"unknown option --dest"

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

VUE_APP_BUILD_FILE=${{ parameters.file}} npm run build -- --outDir ${{ parameters.file}}